Raster package terrain() function retrieves NaN in R
This is my R code:
#remotes::install_github("EMODnet/EMODnetWCS")
library(EMODnetWCS)

wcs <- emdn_init_wcs_client(service = "bathymetry")

x <- rast(ext=c(-15, -13, 36, 38), res=1)

out <- lapply(1:ncell(x), \(i) {
  bbox <- sf::st_bbox(ext(x[i, drop=FALSE]))
  if (all(bbox==(c(2,60,3,61)))) next
  emdn_get_coverage(wcs, coverage_id = "emodnet__mean",
                    bbox = bbox, nil_values_as_na = TRUE)
})

batimetria <- Reduce(mosaic,out)


And then trying these two libraries terra and raster:
#raster
bat2 <- raster(batimetria)
rug = raster::terrain(bat2,opt="roughness")

values(rug)

#terra
rug = terra::terrain(batimetria,v="roughness")
values(rug)

values(rug)

But both give me NaN values and I don't really know what the issue is.

Weird, it's working for me. Yes, there is a couple of NA values, but not so much:
[...]

rug <- terra::terrain(batimetria,v="roughness")

values(rug)[subset(!is.na(values(rug)))] |> length()
#> [1] 3678724

values(rug)[subset(is.na(values(rug)))] |> length()
#> [1] 7676

terra::plot(rug)


Created on 2024-10-23 with reprex v2.1.0

Yep, I realise I was only visualising NAs in the beginning of the values due to borders (and the impossibility to compute closest neighbours). I get the total NA values later on my code:
